# Java:Why changing array' address in a function, does not change its address when we return from that function?

Tags: java, arrays, function, memory-address

I mean that when we return from that function, the address of the array remains the same address it was before we enterd the function.
an example:

```
 class sdasd {
     public static void main(String[] args){
            int[] obj = new int [7];
            //obj has an address
            sdasd t = new sdasd();
            t.func(obj);
            //obj has the same address as before!!
            }
     void func(int[] obj){
        int[] otherObj = new int[13];
        obj=otherObj;``
        //we changed the address of the array 'obj'?
        }
   }
```

thanks for helping

Comment: You are trying to change value of a value, because it's pass-by-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the called function `obj` is **copy of the reference to the array**. So you have, just when you enter `func`, what can be described as

```
  main::obj --> int[7];
  func::obj --> int[7];
```

After assigning the new array, you have

```
  main::obj --> int[7];
  func::obj --> int[13];
```

Parameters are passed by value, so a copy of them is created. When it is a reference, the copy of the reference points to the original object; changes to the reference are local to that method (but changes to the object itself are shared by all the references!)

To put the last point in clear, if you had done, instead of assigning a new reference, something like

```
 void func(int[] obj) {
     obj[1] = 69;
 }
```

then the change would be visible from `main::obj`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the *reference* to `obj` is passed by value into `func`.  So in your method `func`, you've changed the local reference to a new array, but main's `obj` still refers to the original array.  In Java, arrays are objects too, so arrays are declared as references just as normal objects are.

Answer (score 0):

- Thats because when you passed obj array to func() it actually created
  one copy of your array 'obj' and then passed it as parameter.

  So any changes to copy didn't affect your original 'obj'.